# How to train a neural network in forward manner and using it in backward manner

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network

I have a neural network with an input layer having `10` nodes, some hidden layers and an output layer with only 1 node. Then I put a pattern in the input layer, and after some processing, it outputs the value in the output neuron which is a number from `1` to `10`. After the training this model is able to get the output , provided the input pattern.

Now, my question is, if it is possible to calculate the inverse model: This means, that I provide a number from output side, (i.e. using output side as input) and then getting the random pattern from those `10` input neurons (i.e. using input as output side).

I want to do this because I will first train a network on basis of difficulty of pattern (input is the pattern and output is difficulty to understand the pattern). Then I want to feed the network with a number so it creates the random patterns on basis of difficulty.

Comment: I am not sure about your question but it seems that you are looking for encoders and decoders.

Comment: Is there any particular Framework you are using?

Comment: Not really, it was just an idea, i was thinking if there could be any mathematical way of doing this

Comment: You can imagine like it, a person watched some patterns and he learned how to give the difficulty rating to it, then he is queried to provide a pattern whose difficulty rating is given to him

Comment: I guess you should train a feedforward network and when you are going from output to input instead of multiplying weight, you have to divide and also take inverse of activation function.

Comment: OK, can it help, i will think of it

Comment: but again, randomness is not here, perhaps it will provide the same result for given number

Comment: Yes, it will predict the same vaules. You can have some randomness if you train forward network every time you wan to generate pattern from result.

Comment: OK, it sounds better

Comment: What you are looking for is a generative model. A basic neural network is not generative, but there are algorithms for doing this. Look for GAN (generative adversarial network)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your problem correctly, so I will summarize it in my own words: You have a given model, and want to determine the input which yields a given output.

Supposed, that this is correct, there is at least one way I know of, how you can do this approximately. This way is very easy to implement, but might take a while to calculate a value - probably there are better ways to do this, but I am not sure. (I needed this technique some weeks ago in the topic of reinforcement learning, and did not find anything better, compared to this): Lets assume that your Model [image] maps an input [image] to an output [image]. We now have to create a new model, which we will call [image]: This model will later on calculate the inverse of the model [image], so that it gives you the input which yields a specific output. To construct [image] we will create a new model, which consists of one plain `Dense` layer which has the same dimension `m` as the input. This layer will be connected to the input of the model [image] now. Next, you make all weights of [image] non-trainable (this is very important!).

Now we are setup to find an inverse value already: Assuming you want to find the input corresponding (corresponding means here: it creates the output, but is not unique) to the output `y`. You have to create a new input vector `v` which is the unity of [image]. Then you create a input-output data pair consisting of `(v, y)`. Now you use any optimizer you wish to let the input-output-trainingdata propagate through your network, until the error converges to zero. Once this has happend, you can calculate the real input, which gives the output `y` by doing this: Supposed, that the weights if the new input layer are called `w`, and the bias is `b`, the desired input `u` is `u = w*1 + b` (whereby `1` [image])
You might be asking for the reason why this equation holds, so let me try to answer it: You model will try to learn the weights of your new input layer, so that the unity as an input will create the given output. As only the newly added input layer is trainable, only this weights will be changed. Therefore, each weight in this vector will represent the corresponding component of the desired input vector. By using an optimizer and minimizing the `l^2` distance between the wanted output and the output of our inverse-model [image], we will finally determine a set of weights, which will give you a good approximation for the input vector.